# API does not from AngularJS but works on the browser

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using below controller to get data but it give error 'The request failed with response null and status code 0'. However from server status was 200 and it also shows 200 status in browser debugging tool. This API works from both Firefox and Chrome but not using AngularJS.

I am using below code angularjs code to access data.  Why below angularJS code is not able to pull data while it works from browser ?

```
module.controller('bipartiteAPICtrl', function($scope,$http) {
    $scope.data = null;

    $http.get('http://v1.seventh-league-763.appspot.com/getbipartitejs?regionfile=lincRNATSS_200bp_segmented.bed+&celltype1=E050_15_coreMarks_mnemonics.bed+&celltype2=E048_15_coreMarks_mnemonics.bed')
  .success(function(response) {
        alert("webservice completed");
    console.log("Your name is: " + response.data);
  })
    .error(function(response, status) {
    console.log("The request failed with response " + response + " and status code " + status);
  });


});
```

Comment: What does it mean "works from both Firefox and Chrome, but not using AngularJS"? What do you mean by "not using AngularJS"? Clearly, this is an AngularJS controller and `$http` is quite likely an AngularJS service

Comment: It's giving me a 503 right now in the browser.

Comment: API most likely isn't CORS enabled ...check the headers

Comment: If your API is supposed to return JSON data change to JSONP. See here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy

Comment: @QueryLars that only works however if API serves jsonp. Certainly not a fix-all

Comment: it's not working right now just dropping that URL in the browser.... `Error: Server Error

The service you requested is not available yet.
Please try again in 30 seconds.
`.  This seems to be an issue with the API, not angular.

Comment: Never arbitrarily change a json request to jsonp! First of all the server needs to be configured to handle jsonp, but even if it is it's easy to create security issues when using jsonp. If you need to work cross-domain, then always implement CORS instead of jsonp whenever possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When Angular returns code 0 it is most likely a CORS error. Would I be correct in assuming that your Angular code is running on a different domain than *v1.seventh-league-763.appspot.com*?

Websites on one domain are not generally allowed to access a server on another domain. To do this you need to use [CORS (Cross-origin resource sharing)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS). Typically CORS will mean making the server respond with a **Access-Control-Allow-Origin=[client-domain]** header. Otherwise the browser will be blocked, and Angular will return this as a status code 0.

The reason it works if you just paste it into your browser and try to get it that way is that you are no longer trying to access it cross-domain. So CORS is not an issue.

---

Note that some people might suggest using JSONP instead of CORS since JSONP can also work cross-domain, but that is not a good solution! It requires the same amount (if not more) of server-work as CORS would, but JSONP has a lot of security concerns. CORS is the new standard and the current recommendation for cross-domain resources, so avoid JSONP if possible.

Comment: Thank you Erik!! I have to set 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' in my response header.  It working from AngularJS now.

Comment: Great! Remember to accept the answer that solve the issue for you (the checkmark under the counter to the top left), so that others can find it.